# switch tabs from viewpager

Tags: java, android

I have implemented tab layout design and i want to switch to a different tab whenever someone clicks on an image in a viewpager. My research has concluded that a click event is registered on the viewpager adapter however i cannot find a way to grab the id of the tab layout from the adapter.Below is my view pager adapter code:

```
    public class BooksPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPager pager = null;
    ImageView image1;
    private int images[] = {R.drawable.lagers11, R.drawable.stout11, R.drawable.malts11, R.drawable.lagers11, R.drawable.stout11, R.drawable.malts11};
    public BooksPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) ViewGroup.inflate(mContext, R.layout.tab_layout, null);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_books, container, false);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image1.setImageResource(images[position]);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                //this will log the page number that was click
                Toast.makeText(mContext, position + " pagess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);
        return itemView;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                            Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (6);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPageWidth(int position) {
        return (0.3f);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }}
```

2. show_books layout

   ```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:padding="2dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```
3. tab layout

   ```
   <RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/shattered"
   android:orientation="vertical">
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/qb"
   android:elevation="6dp"
   app:tabGravity="fill"
   app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
   app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
   app:tabMode="scrollable"
   app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tabSelectedTextColor"
   app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor">
   </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
   android:id="@+id/viewpagertabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_below="@+id/tabs">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Comment: Please add your layout. It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to use ViewPager with images to select tabs? For examle if i select image at index 1, it should make the tab at index 1 selected?

Comment: Yes @OlcayErtaş that is what I'm trying to to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EventBus` to comminicate between subviews of your Activity or Fragment. First define an Event:

```
public class ImageSelectedEvent {

    int index;

    public MessageEvent(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

than register for this event like:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(ImageSelectedEvent event) {
    //TODO: make tab selected for event.index
}
```

than add register/unregister codes for bus:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Finally use someting like this when an image clicked:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        int index = //get image index
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new ImageSelectedEvent(index));
    }
});
```

You can find more from here:

[How to get started with EventBus in 3 steps](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

Comment: which class do the onMessageEvent, onStart and onStop methods sit? Also, how do I register the tab event inside the onMessageEvent method?

Comment: I have. However, I'm not able to call event.getMessage from onMessageEvent method, just to grab the index vaue. Can you provide an insight why?

Comment: Yo can add functions like `getMessage` but `event.index` is much simpler for this use case.

Comment: The purpose of the events is to carry data you need. So getters and setters is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

> Simple, in `OnClick` of image you should try this

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);
```

Comment: The problemI'm facing is I dont have an handle on the viewPager variable for the tab layout

Comment: you have to make a method in your Activity, and call this method from Fragment's ImageView OnClick. in a activity method you can access your viewPager to call viewPager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);...that's it.

Comment: I'm calling the onclick method from the Adapter, not fragment/Activity

Comment: explain further please